# Finding latest price per product using LinqToSql

Tags: linq-to-sql

If I have a sql table that contains

ProductID

Price

Date

and I wish to find the latest price for a given date. In Sql I can do something like

`
Select * from (

select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY Date DESC) AS row_number,

ProductID,  Date, Price from ProductPrices

where date < @targetDate

) tempTable

where row_number = 1
`

Is it possible to do this easily in LinqToSql?  My attempts have all ended up issuing on sql command per product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
var query = from product in db.Products
            where product.Date < targetDate
            orderby product.Date descending
            group product by product.ProductID into groups
            select groups.First();
```

It's possible that calling `First` won't work but `FirstOrDefault` will - someone else found that recently in a similar situation.

EDIT: This solution was driven from the title more than from the SQL (which I don't fully understand). It aims to find the most recent entry for each product. Hope that's what you were after!

Comment: Yes, that works. It was very close to my Linq attempt with only the select statement different . I was using 
 
select  new { groups.Key , details = groups.First()  }

which seems to trigger the multiple sql commands whereas your solution only hits the server once.  

So thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var result = (
               from context.table where date < targetDate 
               and ProductID = targetproduct 
               orderby date descending
               select new {ProductID, price, Date}
              ).Take(1);
```

Maybe the syntax is not perfect but you should pay attention to the Take(1), which is the equivalent to the row_number

Comment: That finds it for a single product though, rather than the first result for *each* product.

Comment: After rereading it, the body of the message does not make it clear (sorry) , but yes I was looking looking for the latest price per product.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would do the job...

```
var qry = ProductPrices.Where(pp => pp.Date < targetDate)
                       .Max(pp => pp.Date.Ticks);
```